# How to pass product's id to bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I have product and order models. Product has many orders and order belongs to product. There is a button 'Order' on product's page, when a user clicks on it, a bootstrap modal opens up. On this modal I render order's form to create a new one.

I want to know, how to pass a product's id to this form on modal?
Currently my button to open modal look like this:

```
%button.btn.btn-info.btn-lg{"data-target" => "#myModal", "data-toggle" => "modal", :type => "button"} Order
```

And the modal itself:

```
 #myModal.modal.fade{:role => "dialog"}
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} &times;
        %h4.modal-title Order form
      .modal-body
        = render 'orders/form'
      .modal-footer
        %button.btn.btn-default{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} Close
```

I need this product's id to create a new order, which will belong to the product. If I think in wrong direction, please, correct me.

Many thanks in advance for help!

**UPDATE** **Solved!!** Many-many-many thanks to **Arup Rakshit** (@ArupRakshit)!!!

```
  - @products.last(3).each do |product|
     %h4= product.name
     %button.btn.btn-info.btn-lg{"data-target" => "#myModal", "data-toggle" => "modal", :type => "button", data: {product_id: product.id}} Order

    #myModal.modal.fade{:role => "dialog"}
      .modal-dialog
        .modal-content
          .modal-header
            %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} &times;
            %h4.modal-title Order Form
          .modal-body
            #new_order
              = render 'orders/form', product: product
          .modal-footer
            %button.btn.btn-default{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} Close
```

orders/form:

```
= form_for Order.new do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :product_id
  = f.text_field :user_name, placeholder: 'Name', class: 'form-control'  
  = f.submit 'Order', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

application.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '#myModal', function (e) {
  var product_id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('product-id');
  $('#order_product_id').val(product_id);
 });
});
```

Comment: it would be good, if we can see how your products page look like. Does each product has an associated order button in page. Seems so as per the model design, but still I want to confirm myself.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, thanks for reply! I've updated my post in order to see a product's page. I'm not sure what associated button you are talking about. Hope, you can see the way, how I can pass the product id to the modal.

Comment: so it is now very easy, because you have `@product` access. Just pass its value using a `hidden_field` inside the form. Can you show me the `form` also, want to see how it is built up

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I've updated, please check to see my order form. How should I pass a value using `hidden_field`?

Comment: So, one bootstrap modal for each order, or there is single modal across all products.. ?

Comment: single modal. I wonder, how to pass @product.id to the form, which is rendered on modal.

Comment: Try `= render 'orders/form', product: @product` and inside the form write like `= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id`

Comment: where are you ?? :P what happened ?

Comment: thanks! It works great! But now I'm thinking, what if I iterate all products like `- @products.each do |product|`, then how should I make it working? And thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: still possible, need to see your dom. My idea then is, you will use bootstrap `shown` event hook to update the hidden field using js. store the product id in an data attribute of a html dom .. like that

Comment: Arup, thanks a lot. I made it working with an array of products. New orders are saved correctly with certain product's id. You are my hero! It was such a simple and fast solution. Many thanks!

Comment: Arup, if you still here, can I ask you once more? I found out, that when I want to make it working for an array, it works only for the last created product.

Comment: I don't know what you meant by Array. You mean a single order with multiple products ? I am confused now.

Comment: I see, what you meant. you need to use the JS trick I said above. Don't pass the `product` as local var to the form. rather keep the data inside a data attribute, in a dom like `.modal-body{data: {product_id: @product.id}`, then use bootstrap `shown` event, to take the value from the data attribute and add it to the hidden_field.

Comment: Arup, I've updated my post to check it out. I want to create an order for one of the products. An order can be created for one certain product. Currently it creates an order for the last product only.

Comment: read above comment, and see if you get me or not.

Comment: change `f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id` to `f.hidden_field :product_id`.

Comment: I see your post about `shown`, though I'm not sure how to implement it. Could you, please, show me this solution? Or, maybe, bring some link with example.

Comment: I've changed, but now it doesn't get product_id at all. Can't create an order now. Should I somehow update this field with js? Could you, please, write this js trick?

Comment: can you give me the `id` of rendered form as you see it in the browser by inspecting.

Comment: If you mean an id of modal, then it's `id="myModal"`. Or If I inspect a form of any product, it shows: `id="order_product_id"`. If I'm writing something wrong, please let me know.

Comment: check my answer.. It is the idea I was trying to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep the product in the modal button using data attribute. Like

```
%button.btn.btn-info.btn-lg{"data-target" => "#myModal", "data-toggle" => "modal", :type => "button", data: {product_id: @product.id}} Order
```

Inside the form add the hidden field:

```
= form_for Order.new do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.text_field :user_name, placeholder: 'Name', class: 'form-control'
    = f.hidden_field :product_id
```

You need to use below JS, to populate the hidden field value.

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '#myModal', function (e) {
  var product_id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('product-id');
  $('#order_product_id').val(product_id);
 });
```

`#new_order` is the form `ID`, change it to yours one. Bootstrap [modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

Comment: Arup, I did as you said, but now the form doesn't receive an id, can't create an order.

Comment: Are you sure the JS is getting executed ? Add `console.log(product_id)` and see in browser dev tool, if you see the output whenever you click on the Order button.

Comment: @DariaVoronova confirm me the above

Comment: I put the script to `application.js`, gave `#new_order` id to my `orders/form`. Also put `console.log(product_id)` to your script, and the chrome console shows nothing. Hmm, probably, I've put the script in wrong place....

Comment: @DariaVoronova can you put the js in the view itself ? check this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag to see how to do it.

Comment: I put the script to the view. Now there is an error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`, when I'm trying to submit the form.

Comment: hmm, you need somehow fix the JS so that it runs. It seems I wish I could see and type in your code editor. :)

Comment: I've updated my post to see the current situation. Please, check, maybe you see the issue.

Comment: Can you add the Rails error log in the question also ?

Comment: @DariaVoronova I changed the JS a bit.. please modify your JS.

Comment: I tried your another js code. I found out, that I get this error because of other js code (I have for different things) was messing yours. Now it doesn't give me an error, but still doesn't get product id. Your new js code works the same in my code. Doesn't get the id.

Comment: doesn't it still print the product_id in the browser dev console ? Are you sure, my JS is getting executed or not when you are opening the modal ?

Comment: nope, showes me an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` and not working..

Comment: it will tell you the line number, can you tell me which line it is the error ? check from browser devtool..

Comment: Arup, I found out, that it was complaining on my other commented js code (what is wierd). And now it gives me this error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`. tried your new js code as well, the same result. Maybe you could check my code through team viewer or skype?

Comment: Is it the same for Bootstrap 4? Thanks in advance.